# Unable to start a new chrome session in docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-grid

I am unable to start a new chrome browser session in a docker container using Java. Please see code below:

```
package remoteTesting;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class chromeStandAloneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL ("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), opt);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println( "Test executed suuccessfully");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
```

Updated to selenium-java v4.9.0